# Do we have any limit for maximum number of rows returned by SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

I am using a `SELECT` query on a SQL Server table with 33,000 rows, but it is returning only 3500 rows.

Do we have any limit for maximum number of rows returned by SELECT query in SQL Server? Please let me know how to change it if yes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your query

Comment: A query can return billions of rows. Something else in the query is limiting the results. Are there any JOINs? A WHERE clause? TOP? OFFSET/FETCH? What about `SET ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: select will give all records no matter how much is the data..may be you are limiting records by using top clause or limit(mysql) or using row_number to filter

Answer (score 5):

The default in Sql Server is to return *everything* the query asked for. You can override the default via [`SET ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx), but I'll be very surprised if that's what's happening here. Instead, check the sql command for any of the following that might be limiting the results:

- `TOP`
- `OFFSET`/`FETCH`
- `JOIN`
- `WHERE`
- `APPLY`
- `GROUP BY`
- `DISTINCT`
- `HAVING` (Implies `GROUP BY`, but could restrict records where the groups do not)

Answer (score 1):

By Default Sql-server return every thing in your table like `select * from yourtable` , if it has 4 rows or 40000 rows, it return everything.

For this Sqlserver have where clause which used to filter the data. `3500` rows from your `33000` rows , it is not done automatically, either you search on wrong database or you are given a filter condition.

Now if you want to get only limited entry to return, the first thing comes in my mind is `TOP intvalue` clause which return the rows which you define in `intvalue`.

```
- Top
- Where
- Distinct
```

And others as @Joel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from youtable` must show you all the `33,000` rows, If you really have that amount of rows. If I write `select top 1000 * from yourtable`, then I will see only `1,000` thousand. I work with tables with `950,000` rows, so you have to be sure that you really have the amount you said. 
Try again with `select * from yourtable`.

Comment: Rajesh, are you working with a production database? it is possible that you have a corrupt table in that case you should use carefully the DBCC CHECKDB command, I strongly recommend you to read about this before if your db is on production. Make sure you have a bakup of your db and tried again if  DBCC CHECKDB('dbmsrecover', REPAIR_REBUILD) doesn't works